# Windows Phone WebClient Won't Update New Data

Tags: json, windows, rest, windows-phone

I have a windows phone app that connects to a local IIS Server.  It downloads some json data and displays it in a list box.  I also have a refresh button on the page.  When the page loads everything is correct but pressing the refresh button only returns the same data that was available when the page is loaded.  I have checked my web browser with the uri and the updated data shows there correctly.  Also If I exit the windows phone app and reload it the data is there.  Here is some dumbed down code I am testing with.

**On page load:**

```
        WebClient download = new WebClient();
        download.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(download_DownloadStringCompleted);
        download.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://sampledata/data"));

        void download_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
        }
```

This works fine and displays a message box with my json string.

**On Refresh:**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient refresh = new WebClient();
        refresh.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(refresh_DownloadStringCompleted);
        refresh.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://sampledata/data"));
    }

    void refresh_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
    }
```

This displays the same json string that was displayed on page load even though the data has changed.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try adding a time stamp to the end of the URL. like `refresh.DownloadStringAsync(new URI("http://sampledata/data" + DateTime.Now.ToString()));`

Answer (score 0):

How much data do You pulling out from server? Try with HttpWebRequest if you need heavy lifting. I also had some issuses with webclient loading and refreshing data. Every change on server comes with big delay...